# yarn build cases error command failed exir code 64

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I am trying to build my project so i use

```
yarn build
```

but every time i use this i get an error :

```
$ sh scripts/copy-build.sh
mkdir: ../../target/classes: No such file or directory
✅  Copying resources from ../build to ../../target/classes/public
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
error Command failed with exit code 64.
```

also if i run "yarn info" i get " error received invalid response from npm.

versions i use:
node version : 13.8.0,
npm version : 6.13.7,
yarn version 1.22.0

Comment: What is the node version? Try with stable version.

Comment: node version : 13.8.0,   
npm version : 6.13.7,   
yarn version 1.22.0

Comment: it seems that node just got crashed. can you try with a stable version?

Comment: downgraded node to v12.16.1. Still getting the same errors when running npm install / yarn build / yarn info